# Why am I not able to pull the latitude and longitude from geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Here is my code: the alert is showing "Undefinted for crd.Latitude and crd.Longitude ... there is one other thing. I am on VPN with my computer hooked up to a remote location ... I don't know if that means anything or not.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // Geolocation
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };

        function success(pos) {
            var crd = pos.coords;
            alert("Latitude : " + crd.Latitude + "Longitude : " + crd.Longitude);

    };

    function error(err) {
        alert("Error code: " + err.code);
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: inspect `crd` will see lowercase property names as per [`getCurrentPosition` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition). Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: that was it, thank you!!